# reverse engineer  java serialization

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

First let me explain our project.

We have a client server system. Both the client and server are implemented in java. We are reimplementing the client in C keeping the interfaces same and keeping the server still in java.

The way client and server communicate is through java dynamic proxy with remoteid being a network connection. Now, client calls the methods which are invoked on the server. There is obviously the serialization and deserialization going. I want to implement the same format that server expects in C. Being a C hacker I, opened up the packet through wireshark and started mapping actual bytes in java code, which has not helped me much. There are few bytes that I can not map in the code(obviously I am not looking at the correct code).

I havent fully understood whether java dynamic proxy serializes automatically with its libraries or do you need to implement some functions in the class, so that things can be written to the wire.

Can anyone suggest me more human approach to such a problem?

PS: I am not very good with java programming.

Comment: I'd suggest changing the protocol. / `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`s are serialised correctly - there's special support in `java.io.Object[In|Out]putStream`. / Why would you want to convert the client from modern (mid-nineties) Java into C?

Comment: because of performance reasons. Java can not exploit hardware the way the C can do. Java is written for portability and not performance. The client performance is dependent on disk usage which can be tuned in C.

Comment: Couldn't you just write a tiny bit of native code to use the relevant native APIs not available in Java?

Comment: Well using JNI is crude, and not an approach that we as designers are happy with. Although it will work with few hacks but its not a good solution.

Comment: I shudder to think of the road you are starting down.  Serialization is complex as heck - unless your client->server communication is dirt simple and very, very constant (in which case, just re-write it to use simple streams) you are in for a world of hurt.  I'm not sure what the objection is to using JNI - we use it all the time to allow us to do high performance low level operations using C, but keep the bulk of the application in Java. There are some use-cases (and yours may be one) where JNI still has too much overhead, but I'd want to make really sure of that...

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of [Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) for maintaining a cross-language-compatible serialization interface.  You write the message format in a fairly straightforward format, and `protoc` generates code in whatever languages you want for the message objects and serializing them compatibly.  (It's also really good at making sure you can add more fields later without breaking everything, which is really important to maintaining things easily.)

It only handles Java, C++, and Python by default, but [C plugins exist](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns).

Answer (score 1):

> I want to implement the same format that server expects in C.

Forget about it. This is basically impossible, unless you have a JVM on hand to do it for you. Any Java class can define its own serialization format, and many in the JDK itself do so.

Consider another protocol, or forget about reimplementing the client in C. Whats the purpose of that anyway? Generally a retrograde step.

Comment: Well, the reason for doing is to get performance. Our research showed that the disk and CPU utilization are low as java does not exploit hw. We do not want to use JNI as its crude.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather suggest to use something like [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/). With reimplementing of Java serialization in C you're on the thin ice, and if it will work in your test environment - it's likely fail on real data in real world.

Answer (score 0):

As one of the comments suggested - I would suggest you switch protocol. 
java.lang.reflect.Proxy in itself is just an interceptor of invocation. 
 I guess the [InvocationHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html) is the one that performs the actual communication. 
When using for example [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) frameworks, many implementations let the client dictate in which format it would like to have the response - JSON, XML, or something else. 
At server side, there are classes that are responsible for "rendering" the results based on the requested format. 
I suggest you implement a mechanism that will distinguish between a C client and a java client , 
 and based on the client type will use the proper "Request parser" and the "Response writer" 
This way, you will also achieve backward compatibility to existing Java clients 
Another option is of course to use the same protocol, and decide to change existing Java clients,  
In this option, you can use DataInputStream and DataOutputStream to read and write data from Stream which is not just an array of bytes, or a single byte. 
I think that with some experiments using wireshark for example you will understand the correct byte alignment for example for the case of writing a Long value. 
I have auccessfully implemented a protocol reader and writer in the past using 
DataInputStream and DataOutputStream where the clients were not just Java (for example - we had an iOS/objective-C client).

Comment: Well, if I try to stick with the current java protocol, its not possible to do it in C? If I get the things working without touching the server code, I will be happy :)

Comment: I understand. I just think this is a wrong way to achieve interoperability.

Answer (score 0):

Any Java class that implements the Serializable interface uses the serialization protocol specified (with a BNF grammar) here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html

If you're comfortable writing parsers, you can definitely implement this grammar in C, and use it to deserialize and reserialize Java objects.